# Using Handlebars in iframes

Tags: iframe, ember.js, handlebars.js

I came across an interesting error today:

```
Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.
```

This happened because I had some dynamic data in a Handlebars template in an `<iframe>`.

If this is not possible, what's a good approach for rendering dynamic content in an `<iframe>` in Ember? For some context, I'm building something like MailChimp's template designer, using iframes for CSS isolation.